# ng-if and ng-repeat to compare in table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table with id column (1,2,3,4,5) and i have an array of elements. $scope.elements has values - 1,3.

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in elements>
<li>{{x}}</li>
</ul>
```

Using this I have to compare the values inside elements array with id in a table. If both idd matches I have to hide that row.

When I use `ng-if`, since I use ng-repeat multiple rows are getting created for each iteration...

can anyone help me to solve this issue...

---

UPDATE:
    hides2 = [1,3,4]
     ng-repeat="x in [hides2] track by $index" ng-if="x!=3"

But the table shows the values, (its not hiding 1,3,4 records)
     [[enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJuG2.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJuG2.jpg)

Comment: what exactly is your issue?

Comment: @Rakeschand i have a table with id's like 1,2,3,4,5 and i have an array of elements with some numbers in them. I have to compare those array numbers with table id..when match is found i have to hide that table row...

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't knnow how you are using ng-if but it's very simple to use, here's is an simple example

```js
 angular.module("app",[]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,4,5] track by $index" ng-if="item !== 1">{{item}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this.. create a function in controller as following

```
$scope.elements = [1,2,3,4,5];
$scope.checkMatch = function(id){
   if($scope.elements.indexOf(id) !== -1){
     return true;
   }else{
     return false;
   }
}
```

In you template call this method in ng-if as following and pass the id in checkMatch...

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in elements>
<li ng-if="checkMatch(x)">{{x}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what result are you getting by this solution? You need to upload your entire code or create a plunkr.